# QT UI translated to python, but images wont load

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

So i've converted my QT Design and the QRC file to python with pyuic and pyrcc.
When I import the python file of the QRC it keeps saying its unused in the code.
I'm guessing didnt use it correctly but cant find an answer anywhere.
If anyone could help me understand and use it correctly i'd be very grateful.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import backgroundPicture


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.setObjectName("Scanner")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 800)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 800))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 800))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 601, 741))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")

        self.pageCreate = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.pageCreate.setObjectName("pageCreate")
        self.Background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.pageCreate)
        self.Background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 601, 761))
        self.Background.setStyleSheet("background-image: :/image/LogoAndText.png;\n"
                                        "background-repeat: repeat-x;")
        self.Background.setText("")
        self.Background.setObjectName("Background")
        self.create_buttonScan = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.pageCreate)
        self.create_buttonScan.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 110, 601, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.create_buttonScan.setFont(font)
        self.create_buttonScan.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                             "    background-color: #1E90FF;\n"
                                             "    color: white;\n"
                                             "}\n"
                                             "QPushButton:hover {\n"
                                             "    background-color:     #00BFFF;\n"
                                             "}")
        self.create_buttonScan.setObjectName("")
        self.create_nodeUid = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.pageCreate)
        self.create_nodeUid.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 200, 601, 91))
        self.create_nodeUid.setObjectName("")
        self.create_nodeUid.setDisabled(True)
        self.create_label_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.pageCreate)
        self.create_label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 300, 601, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.create_label_1.setFont(font)
        self.create_label_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                          "    background-color: #1E90FF;\n"
                                          "    color: white;\n"
                                          "}")
        self.create_label_1.setObjectName("")
        self.create_label_1.setEnabled(False)
        self.create_comboBoxCustomer = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.pageCreate)
        self.create_comboBoxCustomer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 350, 601, 51))
        self.create_comboBoxCustomer.setObjectName("")
        self.create_label_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.pageCreate)
        self.create_label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 410, 601, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.create_label_2.setFont(font)
        self.create_label_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                          "    background-color: #1E90FF;\n"
                                          "    color: white;\n"
                                          "}")
        self.create_label_2.setObjectName("create_label_2")
        self.create_label_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.create_comboBoxLocation = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.pageCreate)
        self.create_comboBoxLocation.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 460, 601, 51))
        self.create_comboBoxLocation.setObjectName("")
        self.create_label_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.pageCreate)
        self.create_label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 520, 601, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.create_label_3.setFont(font)
        self.create_label_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                          "    background-color: #1E90FF;\n"
                                          "    color: white;\n"
                                          "}")
        self.create_label_3.setObjectName("create_label_3")
        self.create_label_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.create_comboBoxDirection = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.pageCreate)
        self.create_comboBoxDirection.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 570, 601, 51))
        self.create_comboBoxDirection.setObjectName("")
        self.create_buttonSubmit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.pageCreate)
        self.create_buttonSubmit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 650, 300, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.create_buttonSubmit.setFont(font)
        self.create_buttonSubmit.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                               "    background-color: #34c759;\n"
                                               "    border-radius: 20px;\n"
                                               "    color: white;\n"
                                               "}\n"
                                               "\n"
                                               "QPushButton:hover {\n"
                                               "    background-color: #30D158;\n"
                                               "}")
        self.create_buttonSubmit.setObjectName("")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.pageCreate)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.create_buttonScan.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.create_label_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.create_label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.create_label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.create_buttonSubmit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Where are you importing the file? Please provide a [mre]. Also note that you didn't *translate* to python: you *converted* the UI and QRC *into* python; translation is about spoken language and localization.

Comment: in the same python file

Comment: @musicamante added more code

Comment: The background-image value should be in the format `url(path)`: `background-image: url(:/image/LogoAndText.png);`.

Comment: I have changed it to =

self.Background.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/image/LogoAndText.png);\n"
                                        "background-repeat: repeat-x;")       

yet it still is not working and i get the same warning that the import backgroundImage is still unused

Comment: The warning is from the IDE and it just tells you that you're not using it in your code (but this is expected, as it's used internally by Qt). Does the image show correctly in Designer with that stylesheet? I tested it with a test resource file and your code (with the proper `url()` value), and it works, so you are probably using the wrong path

Comment: The paths are correct I double checked, but the issue also is that I'm also importing this design into another main.py. If I JUST run the code I pasted, it works fine, but whenever I run the main.py it does not load since it shows as a warning in the compiler. So I'm guessing I have to link the image to an attribute and not keep it in a stylesheet? Or is there a way to suppress the warning so that the code would run?

Comment: The resource file should always be imported in the main script, before the QApplication is initialized, and just once. Try moving the import in the main script.

Comment: Consider that editing pyuic generated files is considered a bad practice for many reasons (including your issue). Please follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of the QRC file had to be imported in the main script instead of the converted UI file! Thanks @musicamante!